# Deployment of nginx with django on port 80 and node.js in port 3001

Tags: node.js, django, nginx

I am using the following github repository https://github.com/sebaburella/Api-Whatsapp and i want to use the funcionality of this in a django proyect but I dont know nothing about node

This github repository it supposedly works as an alternative of the oficial whatsapp api. My nginx configuration is the following froma this tutorial https://tonyteaches.tech/django-nginx-uwsgi-tutorial/

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/udoms/microdomains/microdomains.sock;
}
# configuration of the server
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name micro.domains www.micro.domains;
    charset     utf-8;
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    # Django media and static files
    location /media  {
        alias /home/udoms/microdomains/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/udoms/microdomains/static;
    }
    # Send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/udoms/microdomains/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```